# Gradient descent for functionals?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent

If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, then given an initial point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we can use gradient descent to find a sequence of points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to a critical point of $f$ (if one exists). I was wondering if there is any equivalent method for functionals? That is, is there any way of generating a sequence of functions $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ (preferably polynomials?) that converges to the function $g$ that minimises a functional $E[\phi]$? For example, we could take $E[\phi]$ to be the Dirichlet energy of $\phi$:
$$
E[\phi] = \int_\Omega{\|\nabla\phi(x)\|^2\,\text{d}V}\,.
$$
I have briefly looked at Sobolev gradients but I don't quite understand it. This is slightly different to my specific problem, as the functional I am interested is the vector Dirichlet energy:
$$
E[\mathbf{v}] = \int_\Omega\left((\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})^2 + \|\nabla \times \mathbf{v}\|^2\right)\,\text{d}V\,.
$$
with conditions
$$
\begin{array}{c}\langle \mathbf{v}, \hat{\mathbf{n}}\rangle=0 \mathrm{\ on\ } \partial \Omega,\\ \int_{\Omega} \|\mathbf{v}\|^2\,dV = 1.\end{array}
$$
Edit: The case that I am interested specifically is when $\Omega$ is a torus with a slightly perturbed boundary or an infinite tube twisted helically around the $z$-axis.

Comment: The always-zero function minimizes your functional.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a normalization condition.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking more from the theoretical side (perfect convergence, arguments for how things work given differing convexity and smoothness, etc) or more from the computational side?

Comment: Sort of both. I would like to be able to compute the resulting sequence $g_i$ given an initial function $g_0$, and be able to prove that it converges. It would also be useful to be able to extract information about the limit $g$ of the sequence given the $l^\text{th}$ term of $g_i$, and also how quickly the sequence converges. Although this might be asking for too much.

Comment: Gradient descent is for unconstrained problems, your space of valid $v$s is not even convex. Without additional assumptions the best we can hope for by way of convergence for unconstrained gradient descent in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that accumulation points are critical points.