# Can Gradient Descent be applied to a functionals?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent

If the calculus of variations is the optimization of a functionals. What are the methods for optimize this functionals? **is the Gradient Descent algorithm useful for optimize functionals?**

I research here and there is a question related to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909263/gradient-descent-for-functionals) the user @copper.hat said:

> Gradient descent is for unconstrained problems, your space of valid
> s is not even convex. Without additional assumptions the best we can
> hope for by way of convergence for unconstrained gradient descent in
> ℝ is that accumulation points are critical points.

I really can't understand that statement I know more calculus than calculus-of-variations. I would like a intuitive summarized answer about this. my question is:

- Is Gradient Descent Useful for Calculus of variations?